# Why do my bootstrap glyphicons get rendered to Chinese characters?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I'm using bootstrap with a customized version of `bootstrap.css` version `3.1.1` using their [Customize page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/). The only setting I changed was `@grid-float-breakpoint` setting to `@screen-desktop`. The contents of my customized `bootstrap.css` can be found [here](http://tny.cz/3c26cbb7).

My glyphicon span looks like:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
```

and renders to:
[image: glyphicon-ok Chinese character]

The `glyphicon-remove` span also renders as a chinese character.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
```

and renders to:
[image: glyphicon-remove Chinese character]

Comment: Is your font in a folder outside of `css` in a folder called `fonts`?

Comment: What doctype / charset are you using?

Comment: @BeatAlex yes, my `fonts` directory is in the parent directory of `css`.
@ow3n I'm using `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: And what charset are you using? Also verify the browser is using the specified charset, if there is an encoding error anywhere on the page the browser will not use the charset you specify. How you check which charset is actually used depends on the browser.

Comment: Any specific browser? Have you checked for extensions &/or malware? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/976782

Comment: Chrome `33.0.1750.152` and Firefox `28` on Fedora Linux 20.

Comment: How about providing a link so we can test for ourselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying over the font files to the server again and clearing my browsers' caches has resolved this problem. I don't understand how both browsers had cache problems, but that's what fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found this too.  For me I had previously moved the bootstrap.min.js to after the html body where I saw the chinese characters on slower networks.  Moving the bootstrap.min.js back to the top resolved this for me.

One solution might be to not have any glyphicons in the visible area of the page on the initial load or place a loading panel above your content until the page is loaded.  For instance like this example http://pathgather.github.io/please-wait/

I wanted to move the bootstrap.min.js to improve load times (above-the-fold content).  Running https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights showed that moving it back to the top did not affect load times too much.  I still have my other scripts loading at the bottom.

Comment: probably also because I am using an old bootstrap (but previous developers have modified it so difficult to upgrade!)  I suspect newer version do not have this issue.